# Ghostview - print error

Tags: printing, ghostscript, postscript, idl

I'm trying to print a `.ps` file produced in IDL from GhostView.
The file prints, but I always get an extra page which reads

> 'ERROR: typecheck
>
> OFFENDING COMMAND: restore
>
> STACK:
>
> -mark-
>
> -savelevel-'

Any suggestions please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a mark on the stack when there shouldn't be (the restore state is above it on the stack). When you try to do a restore, it fails because the top object on the stack isn't a saved state.

I'd need to see the file to say any more than that.